# How do I debug missing headers in CMake project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

What would be the general algorithm I should follow to debug issues such as this one?

```
23:28:12: Running steps for project jumper-qt...
23:28:12: Starting: "/usr/bin/cmake" --build . --target all
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt -B/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/CMakeFiles /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
/usr/bin/make  -f src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt_autogen.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt_autogen.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
cd /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/src /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt_autogen.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
/usr/bin/make  -f src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt_autogen.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt_autogen.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
[ 14%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target jumper-qt
cd /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_autogen /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt_autogen.dir/AutogenInfo.json Debug
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
[ 14%] Built target jumper-qt_autogen
/usr/bin/make  -f src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
cd /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/src /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
/usr/bin/make  -f src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
[ 28%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/magnum_item.cpp.o
cd /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src && /usr/bin/g++  -DCORRADE_IS_DEBUG_BUILD -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -I/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src -I/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/src -I/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug/src/jumper-qt_autogen/include -isystem /usr/include/MagnumExternal/OpenGL -isystem /usr/include/qt -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtQuick -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtQmlModels -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtQml -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtGui  -DQT_QML_DEBUG -g -DQT_QML_DEBUG   -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Winit-self -Werror=return-type -Wmissing-declarations -Wpedantic -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wdouble-promotion -fPIC -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/magnum_item.cpp.o -c /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/src/magnum_item.cpp
In file included from /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/src/magnum_item.cpp:4:
/usr/include/Magnum/GL/Renderer.h: In static member function ‘static void Magnum::GL::Renderer::flush()’:
/usr/include/Magnum/GL/Renderer.h:1838:31: error: ‘glFlush’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘flush’?
 1838 |         static void flush() { glFlush(); }
      |                               ^~~~~~~
      |                               flush
/usr/include/Magnum/GL/Renderer.h: In static member function ‘static void Magnum::GL::Renderer::finish()’:
/usr/include/Magnum/GL/Renderer.h:1846:32: error: ‘glFinish’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘finish’?
 1846 |         static void finish() { glFinish(); }
      |                                ^~~~~~~~
      |                                finish
In file included from /home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/src/magnum_item.cpp:4:
/usr/include/Magnum/GL/Renderer.h: In static member function ‘static Magnum::GL::Renderer::Error Magnum::GL::Renderer::error()’:
/usr/include/Magnum/GL/Renderer.h:2053:58: error: ‘glGetError’ was not declared in this scope
 2053 |         static Error error() { return static_cast<Error>(glGetError()); }
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/build.make:122: src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/magnum_item.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/skrat/Workspace/jumper-qt/build/Debug'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:118: src/CMakeFiles/jumper-qt.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:107: all] Error 2
23:28:15: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project jumper-qt (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "CMake Build"
23:28:15: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

The example project use both Qt (Quick 2) and Magnum, both of these libraries make extensive use of OpenGL. When I start example projects for them separately, they both work well and build with no error. When I try to marry them, it falls a part.

So what would be a procedure to follow in this case? How do I find out out why these (`glFlush`) declarations are missing? I tried adding `find_package(OpenGL....` to my project, with no success. I'm interested in the process of finding out what's the problem, not in a solution to this particular problem.

Thank you SO

**UPDATE:** CMake files here https://gist.github.com/skrat/c5b20d6753e6476a4a0d60227cb73cda

Before including Magnum, I had the same project, where I included `find_package(OpenGL...` and was able to use raw OpenGL calls successfully. In a separate Magnum only project, I don't have to find package OpenGL and all is fine, I assume Magnum's CMake files do the hard work.

Also this might be relevant https://github.com/mosra/magnum-bootstrap/blob/base-qt/modules/FindMagnum.cmake

Comment: Can you provide the CMake file you used to try to marry the two projects?

Comment: @squareskittles thanks, I updated the question

Comment: "I'm interested in the process of finding out what's the problem, not in a solution to this particular problem." - Eh? I would understand the question about how to find source (e.g. a line in `CMakeLists.txt`) of weird compiler flags. But the question about tracing **absence** of the compiler flags is at very *least* quite **subjective**. From me: drop all your hard expectation about what the project and its part does, and *try* to prove (for yourself) why your shouldn't get this specific error. During this process you could reveal a thing which is absent in your code.